# Excel VBA - Cell color Change

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a macro that changes colors based on a value in Column L. If the cell in Column L is YES, then Hightlight Column B cell in Red. However, the Macro below doesn't work or fail. It runs but does nothing.

```
   Sub ColorMeElmo()
   Dim i As Long, r1 As Range, r2 As Range
   For i = 2 To 5
   Set r1 = Range("L" & i)
   Set r2 = Range("B" & i & ":B" & i)
   If r1.Value = "YES" Then r2.Interior.Color = vbRed
   Next i
   End Sub
```

Comment: Why not use Conditional formatting?

Comment: Works for me.  Do you have "YES" anywhere in the range L2:L5?  (Note: not just "Yes", but actually "YES")

Comment: HI Scott, I would to provide to a user and I thought a Macro would be easier to run.

Comment: Conditional formatting is much easier for the user to "run" - they don't have to do anything.

Comment: YowE3k. Yes L3 has a yes.

Comment: conditional formatting is so buggy.

Comment: @UGP what do you mean? I have never encountered a bug, just bad inputs on my end.

Comment: "Yes L3 has a yes" - is that a "yes", a "Yes", or a "YES"?? (I agree with Scott).

Comment: @ScottCraner I had a database table that depending on calculated location is would change the color. it worked, but the conditional formating just changed the range it observes and made up the same rule like 10 times when data was deleted or added by the table. so i switched it to vba and it works much better.

Comment: @UGP then again it was input not buggy, you would need to have made the applies to range dynamic. or set the rules to deal with using full column or row references.  But I do agree in some cases code is best, I personally have not found one, but it may have been needed in your case.

Comment: @UGP That's known as user error

Comment: @user7675421 You need to consider accepting answers for your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim CCell As Range
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set CCell = Range("L:L")
    Set sht = Worksheets("SheetName") 
    If Target.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Application.Intersect(CCell, Range(Target.Address)) _
            Is Nothing Then
                If Target.Value = "YES" Then
                    sht.Cells(Target.Row, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this in Sheet you want to watch.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim CCell As Range
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set CCell = Range("L:L")
    Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'EDIT
    If Target.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Application.Intersect(CCell, Range(Target.Address)) _
            Is Nothing Then
                If Target.Value = "YES" Then
                    sht.Cells(Target.Row, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Just a tip - be careful using `Target.Value = "YES"` before checking to see whether there is more than one cell in `Target` - VBA will error if you try to compare an array to a string.  E.g. If the user changed cells `L5:L10`, perhaps by a copy/paste, then this will crash.  (Life would be so much simpler if users only did what we wanted them to do!)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i modified it ;)